# keep user checked radiobtn checked even after postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, postback, checked

I have the following radiocontrols with Default checked  to "All". If user checks some other radio button and submits, on postback i want to retain the checked button, so users can see what they clicked..How do I keep whatever was selected using jquery?? i am using is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() { 
    var url = 'http://mysite.com/events/Pages/default1.aspx?kwd=';
    $(".SearchBoxAndChoices a.searchButton").click(function() {
    var radioVal = $("input[name='EventType']:checked").val();
    var keywords = encodeURIComponent($(".BasicSearchInputBox").val());  
    url =url+keywords+"&type="+radioVal;
    window.location.href=url;  
    });
 });
</script>                     

 <div class="EventRadios" style="color:#574319; font:13px Trebuchet">
    <input type="radio" name="EventType" value="" checked="checked"/>All &nbsp;  
    <input type="radio" name="EventType" value="Classes" />Class &nbsp;  
    <input type="radio" name="EventType" value="Events" />Event &nbsp;    
    <input type="radio" name="EventType" value="Support Groups" />Support Group&nbsp;&nbsp;<br /><br />
</div>
<input name="KeywordBox" class="BasicSearchInputBox" type="text" value="Keyword Search..."/>
<div class="searchBtnHolder"><a class="searchButton" href="#" type="submit"><span>Search</span></a></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick way:

```
var value = window.location.href.match(/[?&]type=([^&#]+)/) || [];

if (value.length == 2) {
    $('input[name="EventType"][value="' + value[1] + '"]').prop('checked', true);
}
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/agW9g/

Comment: thank you thank you thank you! :) worked like a charm! so you check whatever was passed to the url and if its length==2 means???

Comment: @AnjuThapa - `.match` searches the string (using a regex) for the value of the `type` parameter. If it finds it, it'll be in position `1` of the returned array. That's why we first have to check if there is a position `1`.

Comment: How do I achieve the same thing with the dropdowns? <select id="hospitalDropDown" onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_top')"> 
  <option disabled="disabled">Select Hospital</option> 
  <option value="mysite.com/events/Pages/default.aspx">All Hospitals</option>
  <option value="mysite.com/events/Pages/default.aspx?hos=Dyer">Dyer</option>
  <option value="mysite.com/events/Pages/default.aspx?hos=Carmel">Carmel</option>
</select>

Answer (score 1):

If your server page doesn't redirect somewhere else usually the content is the same. Oh, you can use the server controls and keep the state of the control in the ViewState.