# retain dropdown selection on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, refresh, selectedindex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [retaining selected dropdown option on postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8737025/retaining-selected-dropdown-option-on-postback)

I have a dropdown when user selects the option, the value is passed on to the same url as querystring refreshing the page. after the page refreshes i wanna retain the selected value so user knows what was selected. How do i do this in jquery?

```
<select id="hospitalDropDown" onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_top')"> 
        <option value="http://mysite.com/events/Pages/default1.aspx">All Hospitals</option>
  <option value="http://mysite.com/events/Pages/default1.aspx?hos=Dyer">Dyer</option>
  <option value="http://mysite.com/events/Pages/default1.aspx?hos=Carmel">Carmel</option>
</select>
```

Basically the logic is trap the selection in some variable and pass it as selected equals true but i am not being able to do it in jquery..I don't have acccess to server side code..either

Answer (score 1):

For a clean method you can set a cookie

Take a look at the following question and the replies

[jQuery cookies setting select drop down value after page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358689/jquery-cookies-setting-select-drop-down-value-after-page-refresh)

*But my favorite is to set the selection in the user session using ajax method.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="hospitalDropDown"> 
    <option value="">All Hospitals</option>
    <option value="Dyer">Dyer</option>
    <option value="Carmel">Carmel</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hospitalDropDown').val('<?php echo $_GET['hos']; ?>');
    $('#hospitalDropDown').change(function() {
        location.href = 'http://mysite.com/events/Pages/default1.aspx?hos=' + $(this).val();
    });
});
</script>
```