# keep dropdownselection? what am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection, dropdownbox

I am trying to check if there is hos paramaeter in the url has anything and if there is, then pass that value as the selected attribute to the dropdown on page refresh, so the dropdown option remains selected even after refresh

```
   var value = window.location.href.match(/[?&]hos=([^&#]+)/) || [];

        if (value.length == 2) {
            $('#hospitalDropDown[value="' + value[1] + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');

    }
```

Here is the dropdown:

```
<select id="hospitalDropDown" onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_top')">          <option value="http://mysite.com/events/Pages/default1.aspx">All Hospitals</option>   <option value="http://mysite.com/events/Pages/default1.aspx?hos=Dyer">Dyer</option>   <option value="http://mysite.com/events/Pages/default1.aspx?hos=Carmel">Carmel</option> </select>
```

Comment: And what does the url look like and what does the options look like?

Comment: And why do you not finish this one first? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743701/retain-dropdown-selection-on-refresh

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your options have the querystring *value*—All Hospitals, Dyer, Carmel—as the `text`, but the whole url as the `value`.

As a result, match on your option's `value` with `*=`

```
if (value.length == 2) {
    $('#hospitalDropDown option[value*="' + value[1] + '"]').attr("selected", "selected");
```